# mailto is getting "blocked script" and 404 error

Tags: html, mailto

I am getting BLOCKED SCRIPT (and 404 error) when I click on a mailto link. I see this on Fiddler. Does anyone know why? Does anyone know of a workaround to this?

Thanks.

Comment: May you post the HTML code? And test your web page with a web browser such as Firefox?

Comment: here's the code (it works as html from my machine, but gets BLOCKED SCRIPT when moved the our web server):
<a href='mailto:abcde@fghij.com'><span class='normal normal_link'>abcde@fghij.com</span></a>

Comment: why not put the class on the A tag?

Answer (score 1):

There is most likely some proxy or filter running on your web server that is blocking mailto: links in HTML documents. There's not much you can do if you don't have administrative control over the server.